# Finding the value of $c$ to make $-\dfrac{1}{2}x^2+x+c$ a perfect square trinomial

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> I should find the value of $c$ to make: $$-\dfrac{1}{2}x^2+x+c$$ a
>   perfect square trinomial.

I really messed up:  $-\dfrac{1}{2}x^2+x+c=x-\dfrac{1}{2}x^2+c$, but it seems like $-\dfrac{1}{2}x^2$ isn't $a^2\boldsymbol{-2ab}+b^2$. Can you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need $B^2-4AC=0$ that is

$$1+2c=0 \implies c=-\frac12$$

indeed we obtain

$$-\frac12(x^2-2x+1)=\left(\frac i{\sqrt2}(x-1)\right)^2$$

Therefore there is no $c$ to have a perfect square on reals.

Comment: But is that truly a perfect square? What are you going to do about the negative sign?

Comment: I don't think this is what I wanted.

Comment: @Arthur No of course for reals values in the usual sense, but it is in the form $-A^2$ or $(iA)^2$.

Comment: Can't $c=-1$? I think this is also a perfect square and we haven't studied complex numbers.

Comment: This is the best square we can obtain!

Comment: What is $i$? Or is this showing that we are using complex numbers? Is what you wrote equal to $-\dfrac{1}{2}(x-1)^2$?

Comment: In that case the answer is “there is no $c$ to have a perfect square on reals”.

Comment: Got it! Thank you! I appreciate it.

Comment: Note that I’m assuming c as a constant otherwise we could take for example $c=\frac32x^2+x+1$ but in this way we may find infinitely many solutions.

Comment: You are welcome! Bye

Answer (score 2):

Extract the $-1/2$ from the equation:
$$ -\frac{1}{2}x^2 + x + c = -\frac{1}{2}( x^2 - 2x - 2c )  $$
The expression $ x^2 - 2x - 2c $ is similar to the expression $ x^2-2x + 1 = (x-1)^2 $ which gives that 
$$ -2c = 1 \rightarrow c = -\frac{1}{2} $$
and the final expression is:
$$ -\frac{1}{2}(x-1)^2 $$